# Iterate through list two by two in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a list that looks like:

```
list = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
```

I want to iterate through it two by two, so that I can modify 'a' and 'b' in the same iteration. This would be the java equivalent of what I need to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2){
    System.out.println(list.get(i) + list.get(i+1));
}
```

Comment: list is a valid object.

Comment: Ah, parallel assignment. Thanks, @Ilya.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
list.each_slice(2) { |x,y| p "#{x} #{y}" }
```

Comment: It is a valid array defenition syntax

Comment: Interesting. I haven't seen that p before in my ruby studies. Does it stand for process?

Comment: @Ilya surprisingly, it is. I've amended the response, thanks.

Comment: @Nacho321 No, it's a shortcut for `print`. It stands for `puts x.inspect` where `x` is the value passed as parameter.

Comment: @Ilya Technically speaking it's not. It has to do with how Ruby handles the RHS of an assignment. Try using the RHS of that statement anywhere you'd use an array literal and you'll notice that it does not in fact initialize an array. (Ab)using this when actually initializing an array is IMHO not worth the loss of semantic clarity considering that you save a grand total of 2 characters.

Comment: @MichaelKohl pls you can use the `list = %w( a b c )` syntax and save a bunch more of them ;)

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Or just `"a".."h"`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `each_slice` for it:

```
list.each_slice(2) { |first, second| p first + second }
=> "ab"
"cd"
"ef"
"gh"
```

When you use `each_slice(2)`, you pass in block array like ["a", "b"] on each iteration. Size of array depends on `each_slice` argument.
Then, in block, happens next:

```
first, second = ["a", "b"]
first 
#=>"a"
second
#=>"b"
```

Comment: ...or `{ |pair| pair.join }`. (Aside: when I upvoted it went up by two, so I must have accidentally downvoted before--in case you were wondering.)

Answer (score 2):

Here are few more ways:

1. Using `Range#step`

   ```
   (0...list.size).step(2).map { |i| list.values_at(i, i.next).join }
   #=> ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
   ```
2. By grouping the values by their position in array

   ```
   list.group_by.with_index {|_, idx| idx.even?}.values.transpose.map(&:join)
   #=> ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
   ```

Comment: Ha! I was about to write essentially the same, but thought I'd begin with, "`each_slice` is certainly what you want, but...".

Comment: @CarySwoveland :-) In the quest to post different answer, I came up with this one - I agree that `each_slice` is obviously the apt way

Comment: Note that #2 only works when `list` has an even number of elements. You could prepend with `new_list = list + '' if list.size.odd?` but that's too ugly to contemplate.